# Estimote SDK - Beacons raging in background

Tags: swift, core-location, ibeacon, estimote

First question is better is Estimote SDK or CoreLocation framework? I have app which is finding the beacons but now i must made an app which will find beacons when application is in background or even is terminated.

Comment: Understand that the Estimote SDK is just a layer on top of CoreLocation, so background capabilities are the same.

Comment: ok i will propably use corelocation and how to make app which will rage beacons in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up background detection is pretty automatic in iOS so long as you do it in your AppDelegate and receive callbacks in that class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    CLBeaconRegion *region;

    region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] major: 1 minor: 1 identifier: @"region1"];
    region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];

    return YES;
}
```

You can read more about what you can expect from detection times in the background here:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html