# How to get indoor location X and Y postion when app runs in Background?

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, estimote, indoor-positioning-system

Currently I am working on **Estimote indoor location SDK** to use indoor location service  and I am getting **X and Y position when app is foreground** but i want to also **get X and Y position when application is background** so its possible in Estimote indoor SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You will find an answer in Swift [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061689/estimote-sdk-beacons-raging-in-background)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
CLBeaconRegion *region;

region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] major: 1 minor: 1 identifier: @"region1"];
region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
[_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];

return YES;
```

}

You must adapt this code to use the [Estimote Indoor Location SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK/tree/master/Examples/IndoorLocation%20Example/IndoorLocation%20Example)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you keep your app running in the background (e.g. by using regular location services at the same time … or uh, playing music), Indoor Location won't have access to real-time RSSI readings from beacons and iDevice's sensors, which means it'll be unable to compute your (x,y) location. Just keep in mind you need a *very, **very** good reason* (e.g. you *actually are* building a music player which changes the music based on the indoor position) to keep your app alive in the background, otherwise the it'll get rejected during the app review process.